# Install Anaconda 3 python 3.6 version in Windows 10

Tags: python-3.x, windows, anaconda

I learned that there are some issues in the latest Anaconda 3 python 3.7 version for object detection and face recognition deep learning problems from various posts. The official Anaconda site is only providing the latest python 3.7 version [here](https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/#download-section). I want to work on a similar deep learning project in Windows 10(64 bit) which requires Anaconda 3 with python 3.6 version.

I found several posts providing solutions on StackOverflow for a Linux environment but I could not find any solution for the Windows 10 operating system. Can anyone share with me how to download the Anaconda 3 python 3.6 version?.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recommendation: Learn how to use `conda` by reading [get started with conda](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/getting-started.html). The problem you encounter is a very common case could be solved by `conda`, as an environment manager.

#### Solution 1

Use an environment with Python 3.6 installed, and activate this environment each time to work with your project.

```sh
# create an environment with python 3.6
conda create -n py36 python=3.6

# activate this environment
conda activate py36
```

This is also the preferred way to work with different projects. One environment for one project.

#### Solution 2

The default environment you're using with `conda` is `base`. You can override the Python 3.7 within `base` with Python 3.6

```sh
conda install -n base python=3.6
```

Comment: I agree with Solution 1, but I would caution against Solution 2. Users in the past have borked their Conda installs by changing the Python version in their **base**. This is mainly due to the fact that different Python versions have different `site-packages` and they need to ensure that the `conda` package itself is updated during the transaction.  Otherwise, the `conda` command can become non-functional.